# I'm trying to create an ether token and getting this error

Tags: solidity, ether

browser/ballot.sol:120:18: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
        balances[00x2926ad2f538A0e3A0B667B58B3188c9968513287] = 100000000000000000000000000;

Here is my code where the error lies.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function HBD() public {
    symbol = "HBD";
    name = "Happy Birthday Token";
    decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
    balances[00x2926ad2f538A0e3A0B667B58B3188c9968513287] = ;
    Transfer(address(0), 0x2926ad2f538A0e3A0B667B58B3188c9968513287, _totalSupply);
}
```

If anyone can help I will send tokens once complete.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on the line that reads

```
    balances[00x2926ad2f538A0e3A0B667B58B3188c9968513287] = ;
```

You have an expression that says `something=` but you don't have anything on the right hand side of the definition.

You probably also want to remove the leading `0` from the address `0x2926ad2f538A0e3A0B667B58B3188c9968513287` on that same line.

There could be more problems, or this might not be the only thing wrong if you've had a copy & paste problem. I highly encourage editing your post if this answer doesn't help you.

Comment: From the context it should be `balances[00x2926ad2f538A0e3A0B667B58B3188c9968513287] = _totalSupply;`